# need to apply the prometheus rules from alertmanager repo in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Have 2 gitlab  repos:
=> gitlab a
=> gitlab b

gitlab a - contains stateful set and pod of prometheus and prometheus pushgateway

gitlab b - conatins the alertmanager service and alermanager pod and prometheus rules.

all the pods and containers are up and running.
am trying to apply the prometheus-rules to the prometheus stateful set.
prometheusRule.png

need to apply the Kind:prometheus rule to stateful set of prometheus.
can someone help.
[image]

applied rules yaml :

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  labels:
    prometheus: k8s
    role: alert-rules
  name: prometheus-k8s-rules
  namespace: cmp-monitoring
spec:
 groups:
  - name: node-exporter.rules
    rules:
    - expr: |
        count without (cpu) (
          count without (mode) (
            node_cpu_seconds_total{job="node-exporter"}
          )
        )
      record: instance:node_num_cpu:sum
    - expr: |
        1 - avg without (cpu, mode) (
          rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="node-exporter", mode="idle"}[1m])
        )
      record: instance:node_cpu_utilisation:rate1m
```

---

prometheus-statefulset

```
apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  labels:
    app: prometheus
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus
  serviceName: prometheus
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: prometheus
          image: prom/prometheus
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 9090
          volumeMounts:
            - name: prometheus-config
              mountPath: "/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
              subPath: prometheus.yml
            - name: prometheus-data
              mountPath: "/prometheus"
            #- name: rules-general
            #  mountPath: "/etc/prometheus/prometheus.rules.yml"
            #  subPath: prometheus.rules.yml
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /-/healthy
              port: 9090
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            periodSeconds: 40
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /-/healthy
              port: 9090
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            periodSeconds: 40
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            failureThreshold: 3
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      volumes:
        - name: prometheus-config
          configMap:
            name: prometheus-server-conf
        #- name: rules-general
        #  configMap:
        #    name: prometheus-server-conf    
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: prometheus-data
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        storageClassName: rbd-default
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
```

Comment: Gitlab is a workload of your kubernetes cluster or just a repository where the code is versionied? I didn't understand the connection between the gitlab and prometheus rules. Is not clear what you are trying to do. Please provide more details about the steps you are trying to execute and the errors you are facing.

Comment: its just were the code is versioned.am trying to link a yaml file of kind prometheusRules to the prometheus pod which is a statefulset

Comment: What is the error? Could you post some yamls as example?

Comment: sample yamls attached @rabello

Comment: We need more information to help you. Please include in your post the error message you are getting when try to apply the yaml file and every log you got, to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: there is no error message ;am not sure how link the statefulkind and prometheusrule kind.Need to specify the prometheusrule,has worked on setting the rules-general which was a part of configmap but not sure how to link the prometheusRule and statefulset of prometheus

Comment: You must to have the prometheus CRD in your cluster to apply this `kind: PrometheusRule`, see [this link](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator)